# Partition column is getting added to the table schema in hive

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to create a partition table NYSE_TBL and i am partitioning it based on SYMBOLS and i used the below query

```
 create table nyse3
 (exchange_data string,
 stock_date string,
 stock_price_open double,
 stock_prce_high double,
 stock_prce_low double,
 stock_prce_close double,
 stock_volume double,
 stock_price_adj_close double)
 partitioned by (symbol string)
 row format delimited
fields terminated by ',';
```

after creating the table when i tried to describe the schema of NYSE3 i am getting the below schema

```
  describe nyse3;
  OK
  exchange_data         string                                      
  stock_date            string                                      
  stock_price_open      double                                      
  stock_prce_high       double                                      
  stock_prce_low        double                                      
  stock_prce_close      double                                      
  stock_volume          double                                      
  stock_price_adj_close double                                      
  symbol                string                                      

 # Partition Information         
 # col_name             data_type               comment             

 symbol                 string                                      
 Time taken: 0.081 seconds, Fetched: 14 row(s)
```

My question here is , Why the partition column (SYMBOL) is  described in the table schema? Am i doing some thing wrong in creating the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default behaviour of `DESCRIBE TABLE`.

`DESCRIBE` shows the list of columns that includes both non-partition columns and partition columns for the given table. In addition to this listing, the partition columns are again displayed separately under `# Partition Information` to distinguish the partition columns from the non-partition columns.